# Ember: Reinstantiate bootstrap tooltip after DOM change

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I have an Ember app coupled with Bootstrap. I've got the tooltips working ok for the rest of my application, but it never instantiates for the elements hidden inside handlebars conditionals. When the conditionals are set to true via a user click, the tooltip doesn't get applied to the links.

**View**

```
 didInsertElement: function(){
   Ember.$('[data-hover="tooltip"]').tooltip({trigger:'hover'});
 }
```

**HBS**

```
{{#if propertyIstrue}}
    <a href="#" title="Show Me Something" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="left">Hover These</a>
{{/if}}
```

So basically `propertyIsTrue` is a property that gets set to true when the user clicks another button. When the link shows up, the tooltip isn't applied. I need to fix that some how.

I'm using Ember v1.13. Upgrading isn't an option right now.

Answer (score 1):

You could observe the `propertyIsTrue` property:

```
initToolTip: function () {
  if (this.get("propertyIsTrue")) {
    Ember.$('[data-hover="tooltip"]').tooltip({trigger:'hover'});
  }
}.observes("propertyIsTrue")
```

You might need to put the tooltip line inside of a `Ember.run.next` to ensure the tooltip element has made it into the DOM.